# Cannot build app

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, build

```
Ld /Users/philipptraunmuller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LogInAndSignUpDemo-dihjwfplirlovvaourbylovipaqy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LogInAndSignUpDemo.app/LogInAndSignUpDemo normal i386
    cd /Users/philipptraunmuller/Desktop/LoginAndSignUpTutorial-master
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk -L/Users/philipptraunmuller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LogInAndSignUpDemo-dihjwfplirlovvaourbylovipaqy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/philipptraunmuller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LogInAndSignUpDemo-dihjwfplirlovvaourbylovipaqy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/philipptraunmuller/Desktop/LoginAndSignUpTutorial-master -F/Users/fjm/git/SampleAppsPrivate/LoginAndSignUpTutorial -F/Users/philipptraunmuller/Downloads -filelist /Users/philipptraunmuller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LogInAndSignUpDemo-dihjwfplirlovvaourbylovipaqy/Build/Intermediates/LogInAndSignUpDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LogInAndSignUpDemo.build/Objects-normal/i386/LogInAndSignUpDemo.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lsqlite3.0 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework Parse -lsqlite3.0 -framework Accounts -framework AdSupport -framework Social -framework CoreLocation -framework FacebookSDK -framework QuartzCore -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework StoreKit -framework ParseUI -lz.1.1.3 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework ParseFacebookUtils -framework CoreGraphics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/philipptraunmuller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LogInAndSignUpDemo-dihjwfplirlovvaourbylovipaqy/Build/Intermediates/LogInAndSignUpDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LogInAndSignUpDemo.build/Objects-normal/i386/LogInAndSignUpDemo_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/philipptraunmuller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LogInAndSignUpDemo-dihjwfplirlovvaourbylovipaqy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LogInAndSignUpDemo.app/LogInAndSignUpDemo

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/fjm/git/SampleAppsPrivate/LoginAndSignUpTutorial'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException", referenced from:
      ___53+[PFObject(Private) deleteAllAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke226 in Parse(PFObject.o)
      ___65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke319 in Parse(PFObject.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(ParseManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFOfflineStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPinningEventuallyQueue.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFileManager.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTwitterAuthenticationProvider.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(ParseManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFOfflineStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPinningEventuallyQueue.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFOfflineStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyQueue.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTaskHTTPRequestOperation.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: *what can i do ? Please help

Comment: You just copy pasted your error message. Without providing any information.

Comment: It's unclear what your asking. You need to ask a question so we can answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't added the Bolts framework as per the instructions at https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing

Try adding that and rebuilding.